# How to call extension method when there is a property with same name?

Tags: f#

I'm trying to use [OwaspHeaders.Core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OwaspHeaders.Core/) nuget package, but I cannot figure out how to use their fluent style configuration builder in F#. The following is C# code from their documentation converted to F# (and simplified a little).

```
#r "nuget: OwaspHeaders.Core, 4.2.0"
open OwaspHeaders.Core.Extensions

let config =
    SecureHeadersMiddlewareBuilder
        .CreateBuilder()
        .UseHsts(1200, false)
        .Build()
```

The problem is that the object that `CreateBuilder` returns has also `UseHsts` property, which is what is resolved no matter what I try resulting in an error.

```
FS0003: This value is not a function and cannot be applied.
```

How can I call `UseHsts` extension method, instead of accessing the property with same name?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to call the `UseHsts` method directly

```
let config =
    SecureHeadersMiddlewareBuilder
        .UseHsts(SecureHeadersMiddlewareBuilder.CreateBuilder(), 1200, false)
        .Build()
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using this approach. It does look quite awful, but solves the problem. Since the builder is mutable it is possible to create a builder, call extension methods with it one by one without passing the returned builder forward, which makes the code bit less verbose.

Comment: You could use a type alias see my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66389316/423890

Answer (score 2):

Following on @nilekirk's answer, you could create your own extension method with a distinct name, in order to preserve the fluent syntax:

```
#r "nuget: OwaspHeaders.Core, 4.2.0"
open OwaspHeaders.Core.Extensions
open OwaspHeaders.Core.Models

type SecureHeadersMiddlewareConfiguration with
    member config.MyUseHsts(maxAge, includeSubDomains) =
        SecureHeadersMiddlewareBuilder.UseHsts(config, maxAge, includeSubDomains)

let config =
    SecureHeadersMiddlewareBuilder
        .CreateBuilder()
        .MyUseHsts(1200, false)
        .Build()
```

If you want to maintain the same default arguments, I think you probably have to do something like this instead:

```
type SecureHeadersMiddlewareConfiguration with
    member config.MyUseHsts(?maxAge, ?includeSubDomains) =
        match maxAge, includeSubDomains with
            | Some maxAge', Some includeSubDomains' ->
                SecureHeadersMiddlewareBuilder.UseHsts(config, maxAge', includeSubDomains')
            | Some maxAge', None ->
                SecureHeadersMiddlewareBuilder.UseHsts(config, maxAge')
            | None, Some includeSubDomains' ->
                SecureHeadersMiddlewareBuilder.UseHsts(config, includeSubDomains = includeSubDomains')
            | None, None ->
                SecureHeadersMiddlewareBuilder.UseHsts(config)
```

It's a bit ugly, but it will make the rest of your code nicer.

Answer (score 2):

Both the above are good answers, another way would be to use a type alias, which keeps your code short and fluent and this can handle all default arguments too.

```
#r "nuget: OwaspHeaders.Core, 4.2.0"
open OwaspHeaders.Core.Extensions

type SHMB = SecureHeadersMiddlewareBuilder

let config = SHMB.UseHsts(SHMB.CreateBuilder(),1200,false).Build()
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but it isn't fluent style, because you're still explicitly passing the builder as an argument to `UseHsts`.

Comment: Its fluent in the C# sense. Dotted chains. UseHsts needs CreateBuilder() as a a parameter. We all know the .Net object system is a poor fit for F# (esp. wrt type inference) but is still good all things considered..